# Read data from string formatted as table

Tags: java, string, parsing, tabular

I have a string written in table format (header, list of value below header)
 how can I parse the string:

See my string example

```
titel1           titel2             titel3          titel4
value1                              value3          value4
```

and please note that some times I have empty value.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: What character(s) separate the columns from each other?  We would really need to know this to give you meaningful answer.

Comment: `String s = "titel1           titel2             titel3          titel4
value1                              value3          value4"` is an exact parse of your String. In other words: Without knowing anything about what you want to do with the String we can't help you.

Comment: You might want to look at something more structured, like a [Comma Separated Values](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) (CSV) file to hold your data.

Comment: expected output: titel1 -> value1 
titel2 -> null

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this if you've empty values. Instead, use a marking for "empty", could be just "empty" or "null" or whatever suits you (insert this marks where the string is first built).

Then you've many ways to parse, the most rudimentary being iterating your string char by char, separating your entries using the blank spaces, and your lines using the line jumps, but since you are in java you can probably craft something cooler with .split or .replaceAll.

Answer (score 0):

1) Split the string based on new Line `\r?\n`. This will give you n no of elements in an array each corresponding to a row of your table.
2) Now split each element of the array by `\t`. this will give you an array consisting of each of your column entries for that row.

```
String[] records="titel1\ttitel2\ttitel3\ttitel4\nvalue1\t\tvalue3\tvalue4".split("\\n");
//records array will contain each row as an element
Arrays.stream(records).forEach(record -> {
  record.split("\\t");
  // Store this. It will give you each column value
});
```

Hope this helps you out in some way.

Comment: thanks for reply, but this not what i need. this code will not assign emty value to titel2

Comment: I think it will take care of the empty value as well. The output of record.split("\\t") will be 
["value 1", null, "Value 3", "Value 4"].

Comment: i tried it and return array of size 3 [value1,value3,value4]
but empty value not returned as null

Comment: if you tried with my example, then there was an error, I entered only 3 values. if you try and put 4 values in a record with any of them as blank. then it will be treated as null. 
Else with the example you mentioned in the beginning. It will always give null as 2nd element in the array.

I have made changes in my example. Notice after "Value1" I have put two `\t`. thats to inform that this is a blank value